# DCPromo on Server Core - Password complexity

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

I'm trying to promote a Server 2008 Core install to be a domain controller in a new domain. I have an unattended setup file as below:

```
[DCINSTALL]
AutoConfigDNS=Yes
DomainNetBiosName=samlab
NewDomainDNSName=samlab.local
ReplicaOrNewDomain=Domain
NewDomain=Forest
ForestLevel=3
DomainLevel=3
SafeModeAdminPassword:P@ssw0rd1
RebootOnSuccess=Yes
```

I run DC promo and get an error saying:

```
The Directory Services Safe Mode password does not meet the password complexity
requirements of the password policy. Strong passwords require a combination of u
ppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and symbols. Supply a stronger password
```

As far as I can see the password I have supplied should meet the complexity requirements, and I've tried lots of variants, with no luck. Any thoughts on what will meet this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really have a ":" in there on the "SafeModeAdminPassword" line? If so, I think you'd like an "=" there instead.  >smile<